# Google Map inside Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, google-maps, bottom-sheet

I want to make a view in which a want to show google maps inside a BottomSheetFragment. Currently my view is also responding to user gestures to change bottom sheet state but I require gestures to work on map only (e.g for map panning). I only want closeBottomSheetLinearLayout to change bottom sheet state on scroll. Is it possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorGray"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/closeBottomSheetLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <pl.renesans.renesans.SquareLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".tour.TourActivity"/>

    </pl.renesans.renesans.SquareLinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to implement onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) in this way and it worked.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```